# hiding a div with a value/ output from a php and css stament

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am going to use a button to set a value to a variable, I want to be able to hide a `<div>` using the result from a PHP / CSS statement.

`$day` and `$time` would be set using the CSS `set_date()` function. Example below:

```
//Check if $day is within a business week/day
if ($day > 5) {
    //Hide the div
    //Check $time is within business hours and day
} else if ($time>=9 && $time<17) {
    //Show the div
    //Otherwise
} else {
   //Make div invisible
}
```

That's how I want to do it but it isn't working as expected, any help would be much appreciated!

If necessary, here's the button resource:

[image]

Comment: Is your PHP meant to be inline with your HTML? Either way, you can have a n echo of an html button with its display set to hidden to achieve an effect like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($day > 5) {
           $div='';
        }

        //check if it is within business hours and day
        //if yes show div
        elseif ($time>=9 && $time<17) {
          $div='<div> whatever inside</div>';
        }
        //if not make div not visable
        else {
          $div='';
        }

//if you use $div="<div>i am a div with a " inside </div>";
//then do this $div="<div>i am a div with a \" inside</div>"; the \allows the php to know it must not use the next character as code
```

in your html

```
<?php echo $div;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//check if it is within a business week/day
if ($day > 5) {
?>
//hide the div
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mydiv").hide(); 
});
</script>
<?php
}

//check if it is within business hours and day
//if yes show div
elseif ($time>=9 && $time<17) {
?>
//hide the div
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mydiv").show();
});
</script>
<?php
}
//if not make div not visable
else {
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mydiv").hide();
});
</script>
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the [PHP alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

you can simply do that

```
<?php if($day > 5): ?>
    <div id="button1" style="display:none"> Hidden </div> <!-- This is plain html -->
<?php elseif($time >= 9 && $time < 17): ?>
    <div id="button2"> Button text </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div id="button3" style="opacity:0"> Invisible </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It is really great and clean to use PHP alternative syntax if you mixing HTML and PHP, you're completely clean and clear when using Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `<div>` need to be invisible? Couldn't you just not have an else condition?

With just one conditional you can write

```
if (($time>=9 && $time<17) && ($day < 5)) {
 // Div is shown 9am - 7pm on weekdays
 // echo div

}
```